# Un-sanitize url in mysql or php

Tags: php, mysql

I use a method to sanitize a user submitted string(a question) to an url.
It strips everything except alphanumerical and replaces whitespace with dashes.

Now i need to find the correct line in my mysql db, when that url is called.

> e.g.: url: website.bla/what-is-this

should find a line in my table with e.g. this value

> "What is THIS??????"

I would want to use an id in the url kinda like that:

> website.bla/32423/what-is-this
>
> website.bla/what-is-this_32423

but it's customer request, that there should be no extra numbers, because of seo.

So reversing the sanitize method is not really possible.
What i could do is loop through every entry in my db and use the sanitize method and see if that matches the url, but i think that'll be stupid when db gets bigger.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array("SELECT * FROM questions"))
{
   if ($url == sanitize($row["question_text"])) return $row;
}
```

Or i could "rebuild" that sanitize method in mysql with a lot of chained mysql replace(),
but i think that'll be error prone.

```
"SELECT * FROM questions WHERE Replace(Replace(Replace(REPLACE(question_text,'%',''),'&','')...
```

So my current idea is to just use the sanitized string as a primary key in my db.

Would that be a good approach or is there some other, better or more standardized way than that?

Comment: I'd create an index, not like MySQL index but like search engine index for every single word and its appearance

Comment: I don't think there has ever been any objective evidence that URL's containing ids damage SEO. Rather, I think it's a misconception stemming from the assertion that having a parameter-heavy URL imparts no semantic value about a resource at all, and therefore can be considered harmful to SEO efforts. Over time people have simply started mixing things up; meaningless parameters are BAD, id is a parameter, therefore id's are BAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually what keys are used for in a database. If you have data that identifies a specific entry it is no bad practice in anyway.

But in fact there is a chance that multiple questions with the same name may occur with your method, this is the bad part of your approach. You can prevent this by using unique id (e.g. the primary database key as auto incrementing integer). This also is what is state of the art in most websites (e.g. StackOverflow `http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/20976228/un-sanitize-url-in-mysql-or-php` works and so does `http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/20976228`, because 20976228 is the unique id of this question, and stackoverflow uses only the ID to identify the question. The rest of the URL is only added for readability or SEO purposes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976228/this_is_a_giraffe_also_works . Id alone is used in this case, what you see is display url

Comment: That is exactly what I said!?

Comment: yep :) just pointing out that the last part of the url only has readability relevance and is for seo/humans, and the user can put whatever(check the string in the url above after the ID)

Comment: I guess with the key approach i just remembered that "rule", that you should not store values in one column, which can be created from another column... like: don't store net wage in one column and gross wage in another, because you can easily create one from the other. but i guess with values which are only one-way creatable and in this case the rule can be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

There are good arguments why this is a bad idea, and why using the number as a unique identifier is the best way to go.

- The SEO argument is pure superstition. Stack Overflow use numbers as unique identifiers in URLs (see the above URL) and their SEO performance is legendary. Stack Overflow questions rank in the top ten results for millions of queries around the planet.
- By making them a unique key, you massively limit the range of possible names. For example, once the key `Zurich` is taken, I will be unable to create records with the name...

  - `Zürich`
  - `(Zürich)`
  - `Zürich (苏黎世)`
  - `Zürich!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`
  - `Zürich!!!!!!`
  - `Zürich????????????`

  ... for absolutely no good reason! (They're not mind-blowingly good examples, but you get my point.)
- By using the name as a unique key, *any rename operation will create an invalid URL.* Correct a typo in the name - blam! Incoming visitors from search engines get a 404. That's terrible.

The numbers approach is really the sanest way to go. Look at the number to identify records; to avoid duplicate content in search engines, do a header redirect to the correct sanitized name when it doesn't match the one you have on file. (You'll notice that you can enter any nonsene in this page's URL's name part, but it'll redirect to the correct version.)

Comment: +1 These design considerations are why I would push back and say the ids need to stay. What a customer says they want and what they actually need are sometimes very different things, and part of our job is to align the two...

Comment: I've already talked with him about the similar names issue and even shown him that stackoverflow uses this kind of approach, but... he still wants it without numbers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have already said it: store the sanitised version of the string in the database and use it as a key (not necessarily the primary key, but a key you can search by). This also helps you ensure that each slug is actually unique. Anything else is a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

Store the sanitized key.

Also look into mysql functions, if you have any legacy stuff that needs converted. I personally use a custom alphanumeric convert function for a lot of matching ( add a lcase and you're set)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` FUNCTION `alphanumeric`(`str` VARCHAR(255) )

    RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c VARCHAR(1);   
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF  c REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]' or c REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END
```